# Modal verbs: difference betweeen ¨Would¨ and ¨Could¨

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would, could-modal

I have a question: when I could use the modal verb ¨Could¨ and when ¨Would¨ because for me is similar. I know ¨Would¨ we can use it in very polite situations like ¨would you like a cup of coffee¨. But I saw ¨Would¨ in informal conversations similar to ¨ Could¨. Can somebody help me with that, please?

Answer (score 4):

"Could" and "would" have some special use patterns when requests are involved.

> Would you like a cup of coffee?

^ This is a correct way to ask if the listener wants you to give her some coffee.

> Could you like a cup of coffee?

^ This is not correct; it sounds wrong and would not be spoken by a fluent speaker.  "Could" refers to a possible future event - you are asking if she wants coffee /now/, not if there is may ever be a future point in time at which she might possibly want it.

If however, you are asking another person to do something, they are nearly interchangeable:

> Would you pour me a cup of coffee?

and

> Could you pour me a cup of coffee?

are both relatively polite ways to ask that the listener prepare your coffee.

Comment: I think it's more colloquial BrE  than AmE, but ***I could go a pint*** is syntactically fine, as is ***I could murder a steak***.

Comment: Neither of these have anything to do with the question or this answer so far as I can tell, and "I could go a pint" is so intensely dialectual that it probably shouldn't even be given as a use example to learners.  (It's incorrect use in all american english and also in RP)

Comment: *I couldn't / wouldn't agree with you there*, but it's not worth arguing about.

Comment: "Could you *drink* a cup of coffee?" is also good.

Comment: @WeatherVane - that sounds to me like the speaker is asking about the listener's /ability/ to drink a cup of coffee, not her /desire to/.

Comment: To me, it means the same as "Could you use a cup of coffee?" A "could" usage.

Comment: "Could you use" is somewhat idiomatic, and is closer to asking if the listener wants a cup than "Could you drink a cup", to my ear.